# Produced invalid scale when simulated Generalized Pareto Distribution to find mse rmse and bias

Tags: r, optimization, statistics

I am working on Generalized Pareto Distribution in R and I want to calculate the bias, mse and rmse of the disitribtion. However when I'm using the mle function the following error occured.

```
Error in dgpd(x = samples, scale = scale, shape = shape, log = TRUE) : 
  invalid scale
```

The code is as following:

```
library(stats4)
library(evd)
gpd_simulation<-function(N,n,scale,shape){
  conc<-numeric(N)
  for(i in 1:N){
    samples=rgpd(n,scale=scale,shape=shape)
    gpdlik<-function(scale,shape){
      -sum(dgpd(x=samples,scale=scale,shape=shape,log=TRUE))
    }
    result<-mle(minuslogl=gpdlik,start=list(scale=11.63599901,shape=0.1),lower=c(0,0),method="L-BFGS-B")
    conc[i]<-result@coef
  }
  conc
}

summarygpd1<-function(conc){
  bias=mean(conc)-3;bias
  mse=var(conc)+bias^2;mse
  rmse=sqrt(var(conc)+bias^2);rmse
  return(c(bias,mse,rmse))
}

simulate40<-gpd_simulation(1000,40,11.63599901,0.1);simulate40
summarygpd1(simulate40)
```

However, if i use my own dataset, the following error would not occur, is there something wrong with using rgpd this way?

Just to add, if I increase my sample size, the codes run fine, I increase it to 80, 100 and 120, The code run with no error, but 40 and 60 the error will occur again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your code, it fails when the `mle()` function tries a scale that is exactly zero.  It never chooses an MLE that's near zero, so it's probably simplest to set the lower limit on the parameter to a small positive number instead of using zero, e.g. setting the lower limit to 0.01 works for me with warnings but no error.

The warnings come from the line `conc[i] <- result@coef`.  At this point `result@coef` is length 2, and `conc[i]` can only hold a single number.  If you only want to save the scale, use `conc[i] <- result@coef[1]`.

This code incorporates both fixes:

```
gpd_simulation<-function(N,n,scale,shape){
  conc<-numeric(N)
  for(i in 1:N){
    samples=rgpd(n,scale=scale,shape=shape)
    gpdlik<-function(scale,shape){ 
      -sum(dgpd(x=samples,scale=scale,shape=shape,log=TRUE))
    }
    result<-mle(minuslogl=gpdlik,start=list(scale=11.63599901,shape=0.1),lower=c(0.01,0),method="L-BFGS-B")
    conc[i]<-result@coef[1]
  }
  conc
}
```

A more general solution is to figure out what should happen in the limit as scale tends to zero, and have `gpdlik` return that value when `scale` is exactly zero.

Comment: Changing the lower limit to 0.01 works for me. Just wondering when mine lower limit is 0, the code only work when my sample size is 80 and above, but not working for 40 and 60. Does this means there is something wrong about my coding or technique?

Comment: With the larger sample size, the likelihood will be more concentrated around the true value, and the `mle()` function won't even try zero.  I'd guess that even with size 80, if you run it enough times sometime you'll get the error, it will just happen less often than with smaller samples.